# Bad practice to have a Response.Redirect within a class in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, response.redirect

Within my ASP.NET App I am using a Method to check user permissions to decide whether the user can view the page, or get redirected to the "Invalid Permissions" page.

Since adding this Permission Redirect on the Master Page would cause an infinite loop, I am forced to apply it to all pages. I do not want to have to copy this Method onto every page, so I would like to create a class within my Web App which holds this Method so I can use it globally across my app.

I have had no formal training, but my gut is telling me that it's bad practice to place a Response.Redirect or any "Web" functions in a class? Am I correct? And if so, is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: Where are you going to put any code other than in a class?

Comment: If the 'rules' as to which pages each role / which permission is required for access to a page are external (e.g. SiteMap, Xml file, etc), you might look at using an HttpModule for this level of access control. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401088/how-would-an-httpmodule-for-custom-authentication-interact-with-windows-authenti

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the current url to make sure that it is not already the invalid permissions page before redirecting; therefore, you will only redirect when you are not already there.

```
if(!Request.RawUrl.Contains("Invalid Permissions Page"))
    Response.Redirect("Invalid Permissions Page");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a new class, let's call it `myPageClass`, that heritage from `System.Web.UI.Page`, then, include all the code you need in this class make all your code behind heritable from `myPageClass`.

```
public class myPageClass : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public void authorize()
        { 
            // your auth code here
            Response.Redirect("Invalid_Permissions_Page.aspx", false);
        }
    }
```

---

```
public partial class _Default : myPageClass
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Your code here
    }
}
```

In my opinion, you should not use `Response.Redirect` in the cases of the action of a button, for example, if it's going to take you to another page, you don't need to go to the server to do that, that's only to be made in the client.

Answer (score 1):

First things first, your original question:

> Bad practice to have a Response.Redirect within a class in ASP.NET?

Yes I believe this is a bad practice.  It's safer to pass a delegate, then your 'AuthorizeRequest' method can call the delegate.  Here is an example:

```
public static void AuthorizeRequest(Action<string> redirect)
{
    if( /*whatever*/ )
        redirect("/InvalidPermissions.htm");
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AuthorizeRequest(Response.Redirect);
}
```

**Now the bigger problem... You do not want to do this!**

Having each page assert authorization is a quick way to write security issues.  Someone will forget or accidentally remove the assertion.  ASP.NET has a multitude of ways to intercept and filter requests for this very purpose.

The easiest thing to do is to place this in event hooks in your Global.asax file.  The [HttpApplication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.aspx) object has several events that can be used for this purpose.  Another option is to implement the [IHttpModule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttpmodule) interface.  Either way, I would not write the code in each page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It looks as though I should be doing this from the Application_AuthenticateRequest method within the Global.asax, which is where I would put my Method and call HttpApplication.Response.Redirect?