# Custom FormsAuthenticationTicket validation

Tags: asp.net, security, authentication, forms-authentication

I've got a website that hosts many asp.net applications. Some of written in MVC2, some are written in MVC3, some are not written in house and binary deployed (although we can find source code) and many many more are written in ASP.Net 2.0 webforms. Across all of these sites we use a single login page from a login application. We can do this because all applications share:

1. The same application pool
2. The same machine key
3. The same login cookie name

My problem is they also share the security problem, no cookie spoofing protection.
My plan is to add some extra information (first 2 bytes of ip, user agent) to the login cookie (possibly in the useradata field) and then verify this on every request before accepting the cookie.

My question is where does asp.net check the forms authentication ticket and load the user and can I override this to check a few extra things before using the login.

It would be a plus if I didn't have to add this code to every global.cs and could put it in some dll and reference that dll in the config file.

Comment: On a sub note I added a custom SessionIDManager to see if that would help but that only helped with my sessionID not my login cookie.

Comment: Could you use the Application_AuthenticateRequest event in Global.asax - some relevant comments may be here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/875472/authenticaterequest-event

Comment: The reason asp.net does not do IP checking on cookies is because it's a very stupid idea.  There are way too many conditions in which the users IP address changes, such as when using mobile devices (this can change by the minute) or when a users dynamic IP is changed, or there is a pooled of shared proxies.  Plus, this doesn't prevent someone from copying the cookie from one machine behind a firewall to another machine behind the same firewall.  You're trying to fix an unlikely vulnerability by breaking the users ability to use the site, and it doesn't even work right!.

Comment: A better approach is to simply use SSL for cookie transmission, then you are protecting the cookie in transit.  It won't prevent someone who has physical or remote access to the machine from accessing the cookie, but that's a problem inherent in cookies in general.  Locking the cookie to an IP is just a poor way of doing it.

Comment: I agree with @MystereMan sadly our CMS is not compatible with SSL. It's sadly not that unlikely as I saw several of my users suddenly become hackers Chinese ip address. SSL doesn't help with this as I'm pretty certain my users have viruses and spyware copying the cookies directly from their browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not override Authentication except by writing a new **FormsAuthenticationModule**, but there is a simpler way.
while the ASP.NET pipeline processing requests, At each step, an event is raised, this is where you can tap into the ASP.NET pipeline and do your job.

[image: ASP.NET pipeline Authentication & Authorization steps]

In your case, you can validate your cookie in **PostAuthenticateRequestHandler** event handler.

```
 HttpCookie authCookie = Context.Request.Cookies["YourFormsCookieName"];
 if (IsValidAuthCookie(authCookie))
 {
   // do some stuff
 }
 else
 {
   // expire cookie using FormsAuthentication.Signout()
   // do some stuff
 }
```

this is a useful link: [Forms Authentication](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/introduction/forms-authentication-configuration-and-advanced-topics-cs)