# How to know when login is successful working with the asp.net web application template

Tags: asp.net, templates, authentication, default, vs-web-application-project

I created a new asp.net web application using the template that visual studio has. That type of project create a login out-of-the-box which I configured with the `aspnet_regsql` command to work with my database.

Now, when someone logs into the application, I need to know whether or not the login was sucessful, so I can save in `Session['']` the user name among other things.

I was expecting to find a method that returns true or false but instead in the Login.aspx.cs is just the `Page_Load` method and I don't understand how it works.

I tried associated a onclick method that get the value of the `UserName` control, but obviously, that only works when the user log in for the first time, if the user check "Remember me next time" it won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [AuthenticateRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.authenticaterequest.aspx) event is raised when the user has been authenticated, however in this event you *do not have access to the SessionState yet*. Therefore, to save the `Session` you should consider the `PostAcquireRequestState` application event.

[ASP.NET Application Life Cycle Overview for IIS 7.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252.aspx)

[ASP.NET Application Life Cycle Overview for IIS 5.0 and 6.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx)

For additional info:

- [AuthenticateRequest event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875472/authenticaterequest-event)

Example:

#### In global.asax

```
    void Application_PostAcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Context.Session != null)
        {
            Application.Lock();
            Session["user"] = User.Identity.Name;
            Application.UnLock();
        }
    }
```

---

Additionally, if you are using the `LoginControl`, you can handle the `LoggedIn` event:

#### ASPX

```
    <asp:Login runat="server" ID="login" DestinationPageUrl="~/Default.aspx" 
        FailureAction="RedirectToLoginPage"
        onloggedin="login_LoggedIn" ...>
     ....
```

#### ASPX code behind

```
protected void login_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // set the Session here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The aspx web project template makes use of the `asp:Login` control, which does the authentication for you.

If you need to customize the login, you can roll your own username / password inputs, and then  call the membership API directly, e.g.

```
if (Membership.ValidateUser(username, password))
{
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, rememberMe);
    // Do your custom stuff here
```

...

You can also check to see whether the user is authenticated by using

```
UserPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648345.aspx) for more details